# How to set a height value in jQuery, equal to that of window size

Tags: jquery

I have a search bar that should be fixed to the top when i scroll down through the div, in which it is placed in.

My problem though, is that i don't know how to change the value from 400 to being the height of the browser window..

```
<script type="text/javascript"> /*--this script fixes the navigation to the top--*/
   function window_onload() 
   {
      window.addEventListener("scroll",navbar_reset_top,false);
   }

   var navbar_top = window=400; /*--nav bar high befor fixed--*/

   function navbar_reset_top()
   {
     var scrollTop=document.documentElement.scrollTop||document.body.scrollTop;
     if(scrollTop>navbar_top&&navbar.className==="navbar_absolute") 
     {
       document.getElementById("navbar").className="navbar_fixed";
     }
     else if(scrollTop<navbar_top&&navbar.className==="navbar_fixed")
     {
       document.getElementById("navbar").className="navbar_absolute";
     }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good documentation of getting height value of browser window using Jquery- http://api.jquery.com/height/

Also, you can try setting it up using the below code:

```
var navbar_top =  $(document).height();
```